# Ajax: error callback not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm having trouble getting the error callback getting called when I pass the error function as an object parameter in a function. However, when I declare it within the ajax code it works.

```
var ajaxSettings = new Object(); 
    ajaxSettings.error = function(request, status, error){ console.log('bad failure');};
    ajaxSettings.success = function(result) { console.log('good success');};
    uploadFile(contents, ajaxSettings)

function uploadFile(contents, settings) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "PUT",
        data: contents,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: settings.success,
        error: settings.error
    });
}
```

In this case the error callback doesn't get fired. However if I write the error function declaration in the ajax code it works.

```
function uploadFile (contents, settings) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: "PUT",
        data: contents,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: settings.success,
        error: function(request, status, error) { console.log('bad failure'); },
    });
}
```

I also tried making `success: settings.error` and it will call that function when it succeeds. What is the reason the error callback is not getting called?

Comment: I think your `ajaxSettings` is undefined.

Comment: Is `ajaxSettings` in scope when `uploadFile()` is called?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include the initalization for objects. 
@RoryMcCrossan Yes when I console.log(settings.error) it prints out the function. Also settings.success is getting called properly when the ajax succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle using your code check it [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4xFA/)

You should initialize the `ajaxSettings` before use it

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your callbacks like below:

```
var ajaxSettings = {}
ajaxSettings.error = function(request, status, error){ console.log('bad failure');};
ajaxSettings.success = function(result) { console.log('good success');};
```

... because they are probably not visible in "uploadFile" function scope.